# How to launch "Walkthrough" for my VSCode project on a button click

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there a command to launch the my custome walkthroughs page on button click.
I have my
"walkthroughs": [
{
"id": "Project Walkthrough"
}
Example
vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.view.extension.mycustomeExplorer');  can be used to launch the custom activity page.

or example
vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.view.extension.explorer');  is used to launch the explorer

I want VS CODE button when user clicks it will show my project walkthrough page

OR
any setting which show my project walkthrough when it is activated.

I tried calling walkthrough on button click

```
    "walkthroughs": [
        {
            "id": "Project Walkthrough"
                     }
```

Example
vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.walkthroughs.extension');  I dont see my defined walkthrough launched. How can i launch my walkthrough

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `workbench.action.openWalkthrough` command, as described https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/119725.

Something like:

```js
    commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.openWalkthrough', 'publisherName.extensionId#walkthrouId', false);
```

Be aware that the command is still case sensitive, and the updates are being tracked https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/125414

Hope this helps